# When notification comes my app crashed

Tags: android

I want to implement Notification in my app. My code is below and working fine it's display a notification but whenever a Notification arives app is crashing. I dont know why this happened?

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

   Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
   Intent notificationIntent;
   notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Login.class);
   PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

   Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setTicker("ticker message")
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentTitle("title")
                    .setContentText("message")
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    //At most three action buttons can be added
                    .setAutoCancel(true).build();

                  //noti.number=++count;
                //noti.when=System.currentTimeMillis();
                noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
                noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                 // Play default notification sound
                noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                noti.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

                // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
                noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                //Show the notification
                notificationManager.notify(notifyID, noti);
```

Please some one help me!

Comment: Your code is right on way. but i guess to need to add some `VIBRATE` permission like `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`. i m not sure i just playing chess in DARK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about this but add `VIBRATE` permission in your `manifest.xm`l and try

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

And give me feedback on this.

Comment: @SP i said it's perfect working. OMG! it's very simple. thnk u very much.

Comment: @SP That was a great guess..Well played.. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Just do following things ,**

```
     Intent notificationIntent;
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Login.class);
        //add setFlags
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   notificationIntent, 0);

   Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setTicker("ticker message")
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentTitle("title")
                    .setContentText("message")
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                   .build();
   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                // hide the notification after its selected

                noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

                noti.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
                notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Also give the permission in androidmanifest.xml :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```